# Real time signal processing on using GPUs

Tags: c++

I need help on a basic real time signal processing convolution code using GPUs. I have tried to do the basic CPU convolution programming without GPUs , due to my poor background on CUDA programming that is why I join the forum.

Thank you

Comment: This question will probably be downvoted or closed if you do not add some details about what you have tried and focus your question on a specific task you are having problems accomplishing.

Comment: yes, a little more detail would be welcome. sound or images? for what purpose?

Comment: Please add more details:  what is your platform, how are the signals coming into the platform, what compiler and tools are you using?

Answer (score 2):

this is kinda good for beginners: [UDACITY - Intro to Parallel Programming
Using CUDA to Harness the Power of GPUs](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs344)

This one is from the same teacher, but a little more detailed and accelerated. I prefer this one:
http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=4A8BA1C3B38CFCA0